# Не работает плагин Role Members для дискорда

Tags: discord, плагин

Не отображается вывод пользователей при нажатии (  никакой кнопкой )  и наведении на нужно роль ( плагин должен выводить пользователей в следующее окно подобного рода с нужно ролью )
Может я чот не понимаю как это вообще или тут явно что-то неисправно :/
Если кто нить знает помогите пожалуйста.. [image: сам пример собственно]

https://github.com/rauenzi/BetterDiscordAddons/blob/692abbd1877ff6d837dc8a606767d019e52ebe23/Plugins/RoleMembers/RoleMembers.plugin.js

По данной ссылке располагается исходный код.

А так же ссылка на сам плагин:  https://betterdiscord.app/plugin/RoleMembers

Comment: Я думаю о такой проблеме вам лучше написать сразу разработчику: https://github.com/rauenzi/BetterDiscordAddons/issues/new/choose